# Is there a way to create an SVN user with no access to log?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I am considering outsourcing some development work and would like to hand out SVN credentials rather than grant access to the servers I use.

However, I am a little bit uncomfortable with this and would like to know if it is possible to prevent a particular user from running `svn log` and being able to see file history.

All they really need is `co`, `ci` and `diff`

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, but it's an interesting problem! A work around could be to create a fresh repository from an export with no history and give them that to work with - except I can't think of a trivial way to merge their individual commits back into yours, or merge with work you do yourselves in the meantime - or maybe even a new branch in yours and break the 'copied from' metadata so that SVN doesn't think there's any history behind it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

No.

**Long answer**

All standard methods work or on higher level, than single SVN-command (manipulate **read/write rights** in common), or on lower level (with separate DAV-command, **set of** which translated to single svn-command)

*Here khmarbaise had MISS ONE*

**Thoughts and considerations**

If you can build DAV-SVN command map (using Apache log and hands) and verify, that at the DAV-layer enabled and prohibited svn-commands have not intersections in DAV-side, you disable only "bad" dav-commands. But I think, they all have intersections (*not tested!*).

From other side, if you want only limit access to older history from some point (not totally disable using commands, which I blindly consider impossible), you can split workspace of outsourcer into **separate tree**, for which use path-based access-control.

*Here khmarbaise had MISS TWO*

because he recall only about 1) separate 2) unrelated repository, while you have at least 2 choices:

- Create branch in the same repo from HEAD, grant user access only to this branch
- Create (from exported HEAD) additional repository for user, link it to main repo with externals.

In both solutions user's log will stopped on first revision in his space (due to missing older revisions or missing access to history before copy), bidirectional sync still possible for user with sufficient access-level by using merge.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that some other commands needs access as well to the history (merge in particular)...Furthermore the setup to do that on DAV level is more complicated to configure. One other point to that is that you don't know if the OP is working via http...with svn level this won't work. Path-Based-Authorization will work for http(s) and svn protocol!

Comment: Furthermore it's really nice to blame people is such a way.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the possibility to create [path-based-authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz) you can limit the access to particular areas of your repositories which implies that not all history is readable only in the path you gave access to. I think that should be ok. Otherwise you really need to do a replica and have to replicate the changes between the repositories which is not a simple job in SVN.